# Runtime error 91 “Object variable or with block variable not set”

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

```
Sub FindUser()

Dim ie as shdocvw.internetexplorer
Dim ht as htmldocument

Set ie = new internetexplorermedium
Ie.visible = True
Ie.navigate ("url")

Do while ie.busy or ie.readystate <> 4
Doevents
Loop

Set ht = ie.document

Activesheet.range("b30").value = ht.getelementbyid("infobasic").getelementsbytagname("span") (0).innertext

End sub
```

I get error at bolded text (activesheet...line). But if I continue running code manualy I get the desired value in cell. It's just the error in middle. Please help. I want to get the web data into excel cell. In code I have mentioned only one tag however I will be using more tags to get more results from web.

Comment: I would firstly check if what you try to put in a cell is well done. Try please inserting of the next line just above the problematic one: `Debug.Print ht.getelementbyid("infobasic").getelementsbytagname("span") (0).innertext`. Then, press Ctrl + G and see if the first element of the `innertext` has been returned. Maybe you misspelled a tag name... In such a case, the error will move to the newly inserted line.

Comment: I tried adding Debug.Print ht.getelementbyid("infobasic").getelementsbytagname("span") (0).innertext it is giving nothing and getting error 91 on debug code but if I continue runing code it gives me result value.

Answer (score 0):

The error means that you are trying to access a Property of an object that is null.

You need to expand your method a bit, and check each object before you try to access its properties to avoid such errors.

For example:

```
Dim objInfo as Object
Set objInfo = ht.getelementbyid("infobasic")

If objInfo Is Nothing then
    'no need to go any further here as the object is null and 
    'will throw an error if you try to access its properties.
End if

Dim elements as Object
Set elements = objInfo.getelementsbytagname("span")

If elements Is Nothing then
    'same as above
End if

Dim element as Object
Set element = elements(0)

If Not element Is Nothing then
    'here you can safely access the .innerText property
End if
```

After debugging the above, you can see which object has not been set.

Hope this helps.